# Express a linear combination as a quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a matrix $X = [x_1, \dots, x_N]\in \mathbb{R}^{D \times N}$, and a matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ whose rows sum to one, is it possible to express $\sum_{i,j=1}^{N} A_{ij} x_j^T x_i$ in a quadratic form?

Thanks.

PS: Sorry for the title.

Comment: the function is linear in $A$ and quadratic in $x$, so why would it not be possible?

Comment: @LinAlg thanks for the interest, is it possible show how can be written in a more matricized form?

Comment: create a new vector $v$ by stacking all columns of $X$, and then find a $B$ such that $v^TBv$ equals your expression